# Render BitmapFont in 3D libgdx with ModelBatch

Tags: libgdx

I want to render a BitmapFont within a libgdx ModelBatch. I've only found samples with "SpriteBatch". Of course I can move the SpriteBatch around in 3D space, but it is either rendered before or after the "ModelBatched" objects. But I'd like to have it rendered in the correct z position.

E.g.

- Render modelInstanceA (z=20)
- Render Font (z=30)
- Render modelInstanceB (z=40)

Then modelInstanceB should cover Render Font should cover modelInstanceB.

In other words I'd like to render a font within a ModelBatch context.

```
modelBatch.begin(camera);
modelBatch.render(modelInstanceA);
modelBatch.render(font);
modelBatch.render(modelInstanceB);
modelBatch.end();
```

Is there a built in way to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks, Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST); did it. You have to call it before the first draw method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the models are opaque, you could draw your text with SpriteBatch after the `modelBatch.end()` call, but you'd need to call Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST); before `spriteBatch.begin()`. Then disable it after `spriteBatch.end()` to clean up (libgdx classes by default expect it to be off).