# Draw text in 3D space android - Libgdx

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx

I want to render text on rectangles as bellow image.

[image]

```
modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance1, environment);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance2, environment);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance3, environment);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance4, environment);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance5, environment);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance6, environment);
    modelBatch.render(lineInstance, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
```

rectangles were rendered in a 3D space using above code.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567900/render-bitmapfont-in-3d-libgdx-with-modelbatch) I used SpriteBatch to render text.

```
modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance1, environment);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance2, environment);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance3, environment);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance4, environment);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance5, environment);
    modelBatch.render(rectInstance6, environment);
    modelBatch.render(lineInstance, environment);
    modelBatch.end();

    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    stringBuilder.setLength(0);
    stringBuilder.append("100");
    label.setText(stringBuilder);
    stage.draw();
    spriteBatch.end();
    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

But still I can't render the text in 3D space. I want to draw text by setting different z values and view them by zooming the view.
If i can render a Button with Text in 3D space it also ok.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Set a transform matrix on the sprite batch to position the plane it draws on in 3D space.

Comment: I added , transform(transMatrix, 0.80f, 0.0f); spriteBatch.setTransformMatrix(transMatrix ); But still i cant draw text on rectangles in 3D space. method transform :-  public static Matrix4 transform(Matrix4 m, float shx, float shy) { m.idt(); m.val[Matrix4.M01] = shx; m.val[Matrix4.M10] = shy; return m; }

Comment: when zooming i change the z value of camera position. So when zoom into depth it can view the red rectangle. the requirement for the text also  same.